# How to fetch the values from stdClass in PHP?

Tags: php, stdclass

I am working on my php to search for the values from the stdClass array. I have a hard time with fetching the values from the array because it will not fetch the values and store in the `$body_attachment` array when I tried to use `ifdisposition` and `disposition == 'inline'` to search for the values I want.

When I tried this:

```
if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && ($structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'inline')) {

    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
           $body_attachments[$body_number]['is_attachment'] = true;
           $body_attachments[$body_number]['name'] = $object->value;
        }
    }
    $body_number++;
}
```

It will output like this:

```
stdClass Object 
( 
    [type] => 1 
    [encoding] => 0 
    [ifsubtype] => 1 
    [subtype] => RELATED 
    [ifdescription] => 0 
[ifid] => 0 
    [ifdisposition] => 0 
[ifdparameters] => 0 
    [ifparameters] => 1 

                [1] => stdClass Object 
                ( 
                    [type] => 5 
                    [encoding] => 3 
                    [ifsubtype] => 1 
                    [subtype] => PNG 
                    [ifdescription] => 0 
                    [ifid] => 1 
                    [id] => 
                    [bytes] => 29154 
                    [ifdisposition] => 1 
                    [disposition] => inline 
                    [ifdparameters] => 1 
                    [dparameters] => Array 
                                   ( 
                                     [0] => stdClass Object 
                                     ( 
                                        [attribute] => filename 
                                        [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                                      ) 
                                  ) 
                    [ifparameters] => 1 
                    [parameters] => Array 
                                  ( 
                                       [0] => stdClass Object 
                                       ( 
                                            [attribute] => name 
                                            [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                                       ) 
                                   ) 
                ) 
             ) 
) 



stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [type] => 1 
        [encoding] => 0 
        [ifsubtype] => 1 
        [subtype] => RELATED 
        [ifdescription] => 0 
        [ifid] => 0 
        [ifdisposition] => 0 
        [ifdparameters] => 0 
        [ifparameters] => 1 
        [parameters] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [0] => stdClass Object 
                        ( 
                            [attribute] => boundary 
                            [value] => 000000000000098145058c769850 
                        ) 
                      ) 
        [parts] => Array 
                 ( 
                    [0] => stdClass Object 
                    ( 
                        [type] => 1 
                        [encoding] => 0 
                        [ifsubtype] => 1 
                        [subtype] => ALTERNATIVE 
                        [ifdescription] => 0 
                        [ifid] => 0 
                        [ifdisposition] => 0 
                        [ifdparameters] => 0 
                        [ifparameters] => 1 
                        [parameters] => Array 
                                      ( 
                                        [0] => stdClass Object 
                                        ( 
                                            [attribute] => boundary 
                                            [value] => 000000000000098144058c76984f 
                                        ) 
                                      ) 
                        [parts] => Array 
                                 ( 
                                    [0] => stdClass Object 
                                    ( 
                                        [type] => 0 
                                        [encoding] => 0 
                                        [ifsubtype] => 1 
                                        [subtype] => PLAIN 
                                        [ifdescription] => 0 
                                        [ifid] => 0 
                                        [lines] => 11 
                                        [bytes] => 425 
                                        [ifdisposition] => 0 
                                        [ifdparameters] => 0 
                                        [ifparameters] => 1 
                                        [parameters] => Array 
                                              ( 
                                                [0] => stdClass Object 
                                                ( 
                                                    [attribute] => charset 
                                                    [value] => UTF-8 
                                                ) 
                                              ) 
                                    ) 
                                    [1] => stdClass Object 
                                    ( 
                                        [type] => 0 
                                        [encoding] => 4 
                                        [ifsubtype] => 1 
                                        [subtype] => HTML 
                                        [ifdescription] => 0 
                                        [ifid] => 0 
                                        [lines] => 50 
                                        [bytes] => 3875 
                                        [ifdisposition] => 0 
                                        [ifdparameters] => 0 
                                        [ifparameters] => 1 
                                        [parameters] => Array 
                                              ( 
                                                   [0] => stdClass Object 
                                                   ( 
                                                        [attribute] => charset 
                                                        [value] => UTF-8 
                                                    ) 
                                               ) 
                                    ) 
                                 ) 
                    ) 
                    [1] => stdClass Object 
                         ( 
                            [type] => 5 
                            [encoding] => 3 
                            [ifsubtype] => 1 
                            [subtype] => PNG 
                            [ifdescription] => 0 
                            [ifid] => 1 
                            [id] => 
                            [bytes] => 29154 
                            [ifdisposition] => 1 
                            [disposition] => inline 
                            [ifdparameters] => 1 
                            [dparameters] => Array 
                                           ( 
                                               [0] => stdClass Object 
                                               ( 
                                                   [attribute] => filename 
                                                   [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                                               ) 
                                            ) 
                            [ifparameters] => 1 
                            [parameters] => Array 
                                  ( 
                                    [0] => stdClass Object 
                                    ( 
                                        [attribute] => name 
                                        [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                                    ) 
                                  ) 
                         ) 
                 ) 
    ) 
    Array 
    ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object 
            ( 
                [attribute] => boundary 
                [value] => 000000000000098145058c769850 
            ) 
    ) 

stdClass Object 
( 
    [type] => 5 
    [encoding] => 3 
    [ifsubtype] => 1 
    [subtype] => PNG 
    [ifdescription] => 0 
    [ifid] => 1 
    [id] => 
    [bytes] => 49090 
    [ifdisposition] => 1 
    [disposition] => attachment 
    [ifdparameters] => 1 
    [dparameters] => Array 
                   ( 
                        [0] => stdClass Object 
                        ( 
                            [attribute] => filename 
                            [value] => how-ajax-work.png 
                        ) 
                   ) 
    [ifparameters] => 1 
    [parameters] => Array 
                  ( 
                     [0] => stdClass Object 
                     ( 
                        [attribute] => name 
                        [value] => how-ajax-work.png 
                      ) 
                   ) 
)
```

It should be:

```
[1] => stdClass Object 
( 
    [type] => 5 
    [encoding] => 3 
    [ifsubtype] => 1 
    [subtype] => PNG 
    [ifdescription] => 0 
    [ifid] => 1 
    [id] => 
    [bytes] => 29154 
    [ifdisposition] => 1 
    [disposition] => inline 
    [ifdparameters] => 1 
    [dparameters] => Array 
                   ( 
                       [0] => stdClass Object 
                       ( 
                            [attribute] => filename 
                            [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                       ) 
                   ) 
    [ifparameters] => 1 
    [parameters] => Array 
                  ( 
                      [0] => stdClass Object 
                      ( 
                          [attribute] => name 
                          [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png 
                      ) 
                  ) 
 )
```

However I have tried this:

```
$body_attachments[$body_number] = array();

if (($structure->parts[$i]->disposition === 'inline')) {
    ...etc
}
```

And also I have tried this:

```
if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && ($structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'inline')) {
 ...etc
}
```

It will not make any difference. It will not output the values from the stdClass where it have a value called `inline`.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$mailserver = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
$key = "mykey";
$email_number = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($_GET['id']),'AES-128-CBC', $key);

$structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $email_number);
$body_attachments = array();
$body_number = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

    if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && ($structure->parts[$i]->disposition === 'inline')) {

        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                $body_attachments[$body_number]['is_attachment'] = true;
                $body_attachments[$body_number]['name'] = $object->value;
             }
         }
     }
     $body_number++;
 }
 ?>
```

What I am trying to do is I want to search for the value `inline` from the stdClass array, then I want to fetch the value `what-is-bootstrap.png` to store it in the `$body_attachment` array.

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the value from the stdClass array when I want to search for `inline'` to fetch the value of `what-is-bootstrap.png` to store in the `$body_attachment` array?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Here is the var_dump output results:**

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (11) { 
    ["type"]=> int(1) 
    ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
    ["subtype"]=> string(7) "RELATED" 
    ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
    ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
                                ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                                ["value"]=> string(28) "0000000000004ee19c05879c2d0a" 
                            } } 
    ["parts"]=> array(2) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (11) { 
                            ["type"]=> int(1) 
                            ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
                            ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                            ["subtype"]=> string(11) "ALTERNATIVE" 
                            ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                            ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                            ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                            ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                            ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                            ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                   [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { 
                                                   ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                                                   ["value"]=> string(28) "0000000000004ee19b05879c2d09" 
                                                } } 
                            ["parts"]=> array(2) { 
                                                [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (12) { 
                                                ["type"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                                ["subtype"]=> string(5) "PLAIN" 
                                                ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["lines"]=> int(11) 
                                                ["bytes"]=> int(425) 
                                                ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                                ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                        [0]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { 
                                                                        ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
                                                                        ["value"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 
                                                                    } } 
                                            } 
                                                [1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (12) { 
                                                ["type"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["encoding"]=> int(4) 
                                                ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                                ["subtype"]=> string(4) "HTML" 
                                                ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["lines"]=> int(48) 
                                                ["bytes"]=> int(3734) 
                                                ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                                ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                        [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { 
                                                                        ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
                                                                        ["value"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 
                                                                    } } 
                                                } 
                                            } 
                             } [1]=> object(stdClass)#12 (14) { 
                                                          ["type"]=> int(5) 
                                                          ["encoding"]=> int(3) 
                                                          ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                                          ["subtype"]=> string(3) "PNG" 
                                                          ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                                          ["ifid"]=> int(1) 
                                                          ["id"]=> string(14) "" 
                                                          ["bytes"]=> int(29154) 
                                                          ["ifdisposition"]=> int(1) 
                                                          ["disposition"]=> string(6) "inline" 
                                                          ["ifdparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                                          ["dparameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { 
                                                                                    ["attribute"]=> string(8) "filename" 
                                                                                    ["value"]=> string(21) "what-is-bootstrap.png" 
                                                                                } } 
                                                          ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                                          ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                                [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { 
                                                                                ["attribute"]=> string(4) "name" 
                                                                                ["value"]=> string(21) "what-is-bootstrap.png" 
                                                                            } } 
                                                        } 
                        }
    } [1]=> object(stdClass)#15 (14) { 
                                ["type"]=> int(5) 
                                ["encoding"]=> int(3) 
                                ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                ["subtype"]=> string(3) "PNG" 
                                ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                ["ifid"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> string(13) "" 
                                ["bytes"]=> int(49090) 
                                ["ifdisposition"]=> int(1) 
                                ["disposition"]=> string(10) "attachment" 
                                ["ifdparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                ["dparameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                        [0]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2) { 
                                                        ["attribute"]=> string(8) "filename" 
                                                        ["value"]=> string(17) "how-ajax-work.png" 
                                                    } } 
                                ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                        [0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2) { 
                                                        ["attribute"]=> string(4) "name" 
                                                        ["value"]=> string(17) "how-ajax-work.png" 
                                                    } } 
                            } 
} 

array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (11) { 
    ["type"]=> int(1) 
    ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
    ["subtype"]=> string(7) "RELATED" 
    ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
    ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
                            ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                            ["value"]=> string(28) "0000000000004ee19c05879c2d0a" 
                        } } 
    ["parts"]=> array(2) { 
                        [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (11) { 
                        ["type"]=> int(1) 
                        ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                        ["subtype"]=> string(11) "ALTERNATIVE" 
                        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { 
                                                ["attribute"]=> string(8) "boundary" 
                                                ["value"]=> string(28) "0000000000004ee19b05879c2d09" 
                                            } } 
                        ["parts"]=> array(2) { 
                                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (12) { 
                                            ["type"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["encoding"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                            ["subtype"]=> string(5) "PLAIN" 
                                            ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["lines"]=> int(11) 
                                            ["bytes"]=> int(425) 
                                            ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                            ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { 
                                                                    ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
                                                                    ["value"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 
                                                                } } 
                                        } 
                                            [1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (12) { 
                                            ["type"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["encoding"]=> int(4) 
                                            ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                                            ["subtype"]=> string(4) "HTML" 
                                            ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["lines"]=> int(48) 
                                            ["bytes"]=> int(3734) 
                                            ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
                                            ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                                            ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { 
                                                                    ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
                                                                    ["value"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 
                                                                } } 
                                            } 
                                        } 
                        } 
                        [1]=> object(stdClass)#12 (14) { 
                        ["type"]=> int(5) 
                        ["encoding"]=> int(3) 
                        ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
                        ["subtype"]=> string(3) "PNG" 
                        ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
                        ["ifid"]=> int(1) 
                        ["id"]=> string(14) "" 
                        ["bytes"]=> int(29154) 
                        ["ifdisposition"]=> int(1) 
                        ["disposition"]=> string(6) "inline" 
                        ["ifdparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["dparameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                [0]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { 
                                                ["attribute"]=> string(8) "filename" 
                                                ["value"]=> string(21) "what-is-bootstrap.png" 
                                            } } 
                        ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
                        ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                                                [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { 
                                                ["attribute"]=> string(4) "name" 
                                                ["value"]=> string(21) "what-is-bootstrap.png" 
                                            } } 
                        } 
                    } 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#15 (14) { 
    ["type"]=> int(5) 
    ["encoding"]=> int(3) 
    ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1) 
    ["subtype"]=> string(3) "PNG" 
    ["ifdescription"]=> int(0) 
    ["ifid"]=> int(1) 
    ["id"]=> string(13) "" 
    ["bytes"]=> int(49090) 
    ["ifdisposition"]=> int(1) 
    ["disposition"]=> string(10) "attachment" 
    ["ifdparameters"]=> int(1) 
    ["dparameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2) { 
                            ["attribute"]=> string(8) "filename" 
                            ["value"]=> string(17) "how-ajax-work.png" 
                        } } 
    ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
    ["parameters"]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2) { 
                            ["attribute"]=> string(4) "name" 
                            ["value"]=> string(17) "how-ajax-work.png" 
                        } } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your first output that you mentioned belongs to what variable? And do you need the rest of values in `$body_attachments` or just the "inline" one?

Comment: @HTMHell Well thats belong to the variable `$structure->parts[$i]`. I want to store the value `what-is-bootstrap.png` in `body_attachments` in the same line as `inline` value. Make sense?

Comment: And to what `if` your code doesn't get to? the `=== 'inline'` or the `== 'name'`?

Comment: @HTMHell It wont store the value `what-is-bootstrap.png` in the `$body_attachments` array.

Comment: What is the second output, why is there more than one top level object?

Comment: There might be trailing spaces. Try to use `trim($structure->parts[$i]->disposition) === 'inline'` and `strtolower(trim($object->attribute)) == 'name'`. If you code is getting to the 1st  if then the first `trim` is not necessary.

Comment: @HTMHell Do you mean I should use this `if (trim($structure->parts[$i]->disposition) === 'inline')` and `if (strtolower(trim($object->attribute)) == 'name')`??

Comment: @chrisoojer yes. If it doesn't work then you should show us `var_dump($structure->parts)`. And it would be helpful to know which `if` returns false. The 1st one (`=== 'inline'`) or the 2nd (`== 'name'`)?

Comment: @HTMHell  I have already updated var_dump in my updated question. I have tried both `(=== 'inline')` and `(== 'name')` so it didn't work.

Comment: you can convert stdclass to array by  using array_values($stdclass);

Comment: @bdalina can you please show me an example how i can convert stdclass to array by using array_values($stdclass);?

Comment: @chris oojer, sorry for my mistake, array_values is not suited for this, I will post my answer using json_decode, true) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json_decode(json_encode(), true) to simplify stdclass object to an associative array, because it is sometimes complicated to work with multiple mixed object and array in a single variable.

I just took a piece of the code at this part of condition and loop statement to make an example

```
if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && (strtolower($structure->parts[$i]->disposition) === 'inline')) 
{
```

> Here is the only part I converted using  **json_decode(json_encode( $stdclass ),true)**
>
> It converts the *stdclass* object into *associative arrays*

```
    $parameters = json_decode(json_encode($structure->parts[$i]->parameters), true);
    for($i =0; $i < count($parameters); $i++) 
    {
        if(strtolower($parameters[$i]['attribute']) === 'name') {
            $body_attachments[$body_number]['is_attachment'] = true;
            $body_attachments[$body_number]['name'] = $parameters[$i]['name'];
         }
    }
```

End of loop

```
}
```

You can change your loop statements from object support to an array if you want to convert whole object to an associative array

you can also use this function **get_object_vars( )** it also converts the object to an array but they are different with json_decode in terms with deep I have tried them both,
**get_object_vars( )** only converts the parent object not the sub object values

```
 $parameters = (object) array('0' => 
                  (object) array("attribute"=> "name", "value"=>"what-is-bootstrap.png" )
                  );

  print_r($parameters);
  print_r(json_decode(json_encode($parameters), true));
  print_r(get_object_vars($parameters));
```

and the results are

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attribute] => name
        [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png
    )
 )

 Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [attribute] => name
        [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png
    )
 )

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attribute] => name
        [value] => what-is-bootstrap.png
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The user contributions in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) show that the value is `INLINE`, not `inline`. It's recommended to perform a case-insensitive comparison.

```
if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition && strtolower($structure->parts[$i]->disposition) == 'inline') {
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but it dont work. I cant get pass on the if statement when I have the `inline` value. Any idea?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the result of `var_dump($structure->parts)`?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so it's easier to see the nesting levels?

Comment: It looks like you have parts nested inside other parts. You probably need to write a recursive function to find the nested inline attachments.

Comment: so how i can fix it?

Comment: Like I said, you need to write a recursive function. When a part has nested parts, call the function recursively on all those parts.